# SAP b1 transaction Nofitication to block sales order documents with customers who has Over Credit

Tags: sql-server-2008, sapb1

Situation: A customer has 50K credit limit, and 0 Balance. The customer ordered greater than its credit limit(ex. 54,000). So a transaction notification must be triggered. 
Problem: Get customer creditLimit amount; get customer order balance;

What i have tried so far:

```
IF @object_type='17' AND @transaction_type IN ('A','U')
BEGIN
    Declare @CredLimit As nvarchar(250)
    SET @CredLimit= (SELECT T0.CreditLine FROM OCRD T0
     WHERE T0.CardCode=@list_of_cols_val_tab_del)

IF (
    SELECT (T0.DocTotal+T1.Balance) FROM ORDR T0 INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode=T1.CardCode
    WHERE DocStatus='O' AND T1.DocEntry=@list_of_cols_val_tab_del) > @CredLimit
    BEGIN   
        Set @error = -1
        SET @error_message = 'Business Partner is Over Credit Limit! Save this document as DRAFT, thank you'
    END
END
```

The SAP b1 has its own system define notification on credit limit, but we do not want to answer its "Yes or No", we just want to inform the encoder of SO that the Sales order is now making the customer Over CL and therefore save the SO as Draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF @object_type='17' AND @transaction_type IN ('A','U')
BEGIN
    Declare @CredLimit As nvarchar(250)
    SET @CredLimit= (SELECT T0.CreditLine FROM OCRD T0
                     WHERE T0.CardCode=(SELECT CardCode FROM ORDR 
                                        WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del)

IF (
    SELECT (T0.DocTotal+T1.Balance) 
    FROM ORDR T0 
    INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode=T1.CardCode
    WHERE DocStatus='O' AND T1.DocEntry=@list_of_cols_val_tab_del) > @CredLimit
    BEGIN   
        Set @error = -1
        SET @error_message = 'Business Partner is Over Credit Limit! Save this document as DRAFT, thank you'
    END
END
```

The issue is that in the `SET @CredLimit` statement was checking if `T0.CardCode` was equal to `@list_of_cols_val_tab_del`, which is actually the `DocEntry` of the order. Actually, now that I look at it, you could even do something like

```
IF @object_type='17' AND @transaction_type IN ('A','U')
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT T0.DocEntry
        FROM ORDR T0 
        INNER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode=T1.CardCode
        WHERE DocStatus='O' 
        AND T1.DocEntry=@list_of_cols_val_tab_del
        AND (T0.DocTotal + T1.Balance) > T1.CreditLine)
    BEGIN   
        Set @error = -1
        SET @error_message = 'Business Partner is Over Credit Limit! Save this document as DRAFT, thank you'
    END
END
```

In this second version, you completely ignore the unnecessary step of declaring a variable.